# find the smallest possible length of the vector v

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Q1. Let v = $(-2/3,b,16/7)$ and w=$(3/4,-12/5,c)$ be vectors in $R^3$

(a)Find the smallest possible length of vector

My Effort:
v= $(-2/3,b,16/7)$

|a|=$\sqrt{((-2/3)^2+b^2+(16/7)^2)}$

=$\sqrt{(50/21 +b^2)}$

Is this correct for the smallest possible length

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What has $\vec w$ got to do with the question?

Comment: What's that “(a)” doing there?

Comment: Your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863609/range-of-a-multivariable-functionfind-a-point) was closed because, I assume, it showed no effort at all.  This one is likely to be closed for the same reason.

Comment: my problem with the question is the "smallest possible length". in my research I can only find solution to find the magnitude or length of a vector not the smallest possible length.

Comment: The implication here is that $b$ is a parameter which you can set.  Your goal is to find the value of $b$ which makes the length a minimum.  Hint:  it is really, really obvious what value of $b$ you should take.

Comment: What about $b=0$? The key point is that $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is strictly increasing therefore the minimum value is reached for x minimum. In our case $x=50/21+b^2$.

Comment: I feel like you're missing a part of the question and it relies on the fact they're orthogonal. You should check the book and then if they are. Taking the dot product and find out where they are zero. Otherwise, why is $w$ there.

Comment: @javkflow Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall the definition of length, that is $$\vec u=(A,B,C)\implies \|\vec u\|=\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}\ge 0$$

and that

- $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is strictly increasing
- for any $y\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $y^2\ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{-2}{3}\right)^2+b^2+\left(\frac{16}{7}\right)^2}$$